# Mathematics of paper fold-cutting

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

### Take a square of paper...

[image]

### ... and fold it any number of times using consecutive straight folds...

[image]

### ... then cut off any number of pieces using consecutive straight cuts...

[image]

### ... and unfold the remaining piece*

* Condition: The remaining piece must still have at least one fold.

[image]

My question:

## Which shapes can be made this way?

#### Some initial ideas:

- The resulting shape is always a polygon, *but*
- it can be concave *or* convex and
- does not need to have any symmetries.
- The condition (*) is necessary because otherwise it is trivial to make any polygon by simply cutting it out and discarding everything else, at least if incomplete straight cuts are allowed.

The procedure leaves a strong feeling that it somehow limits the class of polygons that can be created but alas, I have not been able to find *any* polygon for which I can prove that it is not an element of that class. Neither have I shown that every polygon can be created that way.

Every *regular* polygon ($n$-gon) can be created by collapsing the square into $n$ radial sections around its center and then making a single symmetric cut.

Comment: The remaining piece in your question doesn't look like it has any folds left in it (unless I don't understand the **noun** *fold*).

Comment: @barak: I think they mean the resulting shape must have a *crease* in it, that is, a fold passed through it previously.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a polygon, as you can generate shapes with holes. But surely it has to be a polygon or a difference of two or more polygons.

Comment: @Rahul: What I actually meant is that the piece must have at least one fold left *before unfolding*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is pretty much any shape. See [Demaine, Demaine, & Lubiw "Folding and Cutting Paper"](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-540-46515-7_9.pdf), which describes a method that uses just one straight cut. (So I believe your condition on requiring a fold can be satisified by simply folding once more along any line perpendicular to the single cut to be made.)

Comment: This is pretty incredible!